# Setting the WebSocket Encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, websocket

How can one set the WebSocket encoding to a specific encoding, such as "UTF-8" or "UTF-16" in a cross platform way?

Every time I send the character "§", it comes out as "Â", which isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

When including a script file, just set the encoding as follows.

```
<script src="url" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

WebSockets seem to comply with this encoding.